# Excel Countifs shorten

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

currently I´m trying to compare a huge dataset and have a problem figuring out how to check if a whole row contains the same values.

```
Countifs(B56;"=Y";C56;"=Y";D56;"=Y";E56;"=Y";F56;"=Y";G56;"=Y";H56;"=Y";I56;"=Y";J56;"=Y")+
Countifs(B57;"=Y";C57;"=Y";D57;"=Y";E57;"=Y";F57;"=Y";G57;"=Y";H57;"=Y";I57;"=Y";J57;"=Y")
```

This is it shortened, it actually should check arround 60 rows with at least 30 columns. It works absolutly fine, my problem is the maximum formular length. 
The only way I know to get it working is by separating the countifs and later sum it. Which I really would like to escape.

Is there a way to check if an whole row(range) only contains KeyX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a continuous range (which seems you have), you can do it much shorter:

`=COUNTIF(B56:J57,"<>Y")=0`

Example with all "Y":
[image]

Example with one of the values different:
[image]

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(B8:P8;"Y");1;0)` this way I had it before, but did not worked cause it counted as soon as 1 value is Y. Your way does it perfectly. Just one thing, I need to check them separately to count which rows are correct. So `=IF(COUNTIF(B56:J56,"<>Y"),0,1)+IF(COUNTIF(B57:J57,"<>Y"),0,1)` Still a little bit long but works like a charm ty very much.